ffmpeg not rendering all characters
am trying to burn captions on a video using below ass file
[Script Info]
; // 此字幕由爱幕生成
Synch Point:1
ScriptType:v4.00+
Collisions:Normal

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default, Cairo, 58px, &H00080808, &H00080808, &HXX000000, &H00C5E71E, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 10, 10, 10, 134

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Actor, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:04.00,Default,NTP,0000,0000,0000,,قم بمضاعفة هذه الأطباق، وإلا قد تحدث فوضى كاملة على يديك.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:04.00,0:00:07.00,Default,NTP,0000,0000,0000,,لا تحصل على أطباق ورقية يمكن أن تجعلك تشعر باللون الأزرق.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.00,0:00:09.00,Default,NTP,0000,0000,0000,,احصل على لوحات ديكسي الترا.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:09.00,0:00:11.00,Default,NTP,0000,0000,0000,,أقوى بثلاث مرات من العلامة التجارية الرائدة في المتجر.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.00,0:00:13.00,Default,NTP,0000,0000,0000,,ديكسي.\Nصححها.

for some reason, not all characters are rendered correctly, I get output similar to this

what could the reason and what's the fix ?
I tried with another font and getting similar results


You probably need to choose a different font, it seems that your chosen font "Cairo" does not have the full set of symbols for your text and ffmpeg is not doing font substitution.

it appears okey if I use it with CSS ... am pretty sure the font file is not the cause

tested, looks good with ffmpeg version N-114921-g2f3c1e1641-20240422 → [Parsed_ass_0 @ 0x7a6044001b00] fontselect: (Cairo, 400, 0) -> /home/bayar/.fonts/Cairo-Regular.ttf, 0, Cairo-Regular

possible lead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73513775/ffmpeg-text-is-not-rendering-for-indian-local-language-font
